# Jenkinsfile path location "@2 converted to %402" and build is failing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have one Jenkins job which does following things

1. Checks out the Jenkinsfile from github at some location (c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build)
2. Jenkinsfile checks out java source code to (c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build@2)
3. mvn clean install

When I run "mvn clean install" on my build machine it works perfectly fine.

But when I run it thorough Jenkisnfile I have few unit test cases which runs when building my project, those units tests are failing with java.io.FileNotFoundException(The system cannot find the path specified) exception/error.

When I ran maven in debug mode(using -X) I found out the workspace path(c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build@2) is being converted to c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build%402 hence maven is unable to find the file which is required for my unit test cases to pass.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you at all? If so, consider upvote and/or accepted. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by using a custom workspace. Something like this

```
ws("c:\jenkins\my_custom_location") {
    // git checkout
    // mvn clean install  
}
```

Jenkins didn't create any directory with @2 or @3 when using custom workspace.

Answer (score 0):

@user3847894,

You did not fix the issue, merely worked around the problem (avoidance). Now, if you run builds in parallel, they will all use the same workspace, probably with horribly unintended consequences.

You can try choose a different symbol:

> [hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#hudson-slaves-workspacelist)
> Since: 1.424 Default:
> @ Description:  When concurrent builds is
> enabled, a unique workspace directory name is required for each
> concurrent build. To create this name, this token is placed between
> project name and a unique ID, e.g. "my-project@123".

Or figure out the real problem:
where your system is pulling the wrong character set (ANSI vs UTF-8 ?  [`locale`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale)), [encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding) or something is wrongly "sanitizing the path" (eg: [OWASP Sanitizer](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-html-sanitizer/)).

You'd have to provide way more info re: OS, jdk, system and startup parameters, etc to diagnose, list of plugins (maven and Jenkins), so can't help further. Check controller and agent system info (`${JENKINS_URL}/systemInfo` and  `${JENKINS_URL}/computer/myNode/systemInfo`) and also see what maven reports in the settings and `help:system`. On your own; good luck

Comment: thanks I will try out your suggestion. I know if I run parallel builds it will mess up but I don't need to run parallel build and for safety I had already disabled parallel builds.